How many times can I update my android app name in Google Play Console? Is there any policy?
How many times can I update my app name in Google Play Console? Is there any policy I can update only few times?
I have checked Developer policy website couldn't find any information how many times I can update my app name

Generally, there is no strict rule for changing the app name; I've updated it a few times, but there will be a review process.

There is no such limits as of now. You can update the app name as many times as you want. But after changing name your app will go through Google's review process again. Changing the name frequently also impacts in visibility and rankings in the playstore. Moreover if you change names too frequently many times then your app may be flagged and may go through additional review.
So, it is not recommended to change names so frequently.

You are right, thanks
